# Access value set using javascript in code behind in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Im executing javascript on a master page that is onClick event of a Menu item i set it to a hidden field and on Init of the Master page im not able to access this hidden field value.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

State isn't available in your controls until the Load phase.  Before that you have to check in `Request.Form`

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply I checked with the Request.Form the count is Zero is there any other way to possibly get this value in the code behind ?

Comment: I also tried the same in the OnLoad and the Page_Load event still is always empty!

Comment: You need to post code then.  What does your hidden field look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code. In Master Page, I add the tag

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPath" runat="server" Value=""/>
```

Then I have a script tag which runs a function `setScript()` that is every time Master Page is loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    setScript();
    // I Navigate through all the menu items, which is navigate
    // through all the "a" tags and then all of the a tags onclick
    // event i add a new function ,below is the code

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    setScript();
    
    function setScript() {
        var objMenu=document.getElementById('<%=_menu.ClientID %>');
        var objHyperLinks=objMenu.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i=0;i<objHyperLinks.length;i++) {
            var pageLoc=objHyperLinks[i].href;
            objHyperLinks.item(i).onclick=function (){
                return setEvent(this);
            };
        }
    }
    
    function setEvent(Loc) {
        var pageLoc=Loc+"";
        var iframePath=document.location.href;
        var targetPath=pageLoc;
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnPath.ClientID %>').value=targetPath;

        if(document.all) {
            document.all.frameLoader.src=targetPath;
        } else {
            var frame=window.frames;
            frame[0].location.href=targetPath;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I alert the value of hdnPath right after the `targetPath` is assigned and I get to see the assigned value.